# Linux Server on old pc:Old version of Ubuntu or Lubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, vpn

I have an old Acer All-in-one with these specs:
- CPU: Intel Celeron 500 Mhz
- RAM: 512 MB
- HDD: 10 GB IDE
- VGA: Integrated
- CD-ROM
- Floppy Disk

My goal is to create a small server that works as printer server and VPN.
Should I use a old version of Ubuntu, Lubuntu, or a different Linux distro?

Comment: You don't even need any GUI for a server, forget about default Ubuntu or Lubuntu, there's a ubuntu server edition for that. Or plain Debian. Or one of a thousand others.

Answer (score 4):

**You do not want an old version of anything, because that will definitely have very serious security issues.** As for which distro is most suitable to such old hardware, that is probably off topic, but a quick search found these recent articles:

- [10 Best Lightweight Linux Distros For Old Computers](https://fossbytes.com/best-lightweight-linux-distros/)
- [4 Best Linux Distros for Older Hardware](https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2017/10/4-best-linux-distros-older-hardware%20)

Comment: An old version is just fine to work as a printer server if the network is sufficiently secured.  "You do not want an old version", due to security concerns, is generally good advice, but to say that is unacceptable for "anything" can be quite misleading.

Comment: @TOOGAM Each to his own, I suppose. I would not expect anyone running an unpatched server to know what a sufficiently secured network even looks like, much less how to create one.

Comment: @toogam except one of the tasks is a VPN server - so you really don't want excessively outdated libraries on it.  Also, there are significant  known attacks on SAMBA from about Oct last year which you really want to mitigate.

Answer (score 1):

Plain old Debian stable (9.x, aka Stretch) will run fine, as should Ubuntu server, Slackware, or any other 32bit compiled modern Linux distro that doesn't require the use of a heavy desktop environment.  Use a light weight window manager (Fluxbox, etc) OR go console only.